# jQuery append() makes error in JQM plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am beginner for jQuery mobile. I am developing jQuery mobile app. When I click `Add_details`, I need to append dynamic inputs for 1 time. After saving, if click the `Add_details` for a second time, I need to append the dynamic inputs. The process is like, every time I click the button i want to Save the values.

This is my code:

I am using JQM datebox plugin for datepicker. It is making error when I try save the values. jQuery `append()` is not accepting the Symbols like %, /. So please anyone help me to solve the issue..

```
 $("#add_Details").click(function () {
    $("#child_service_details").append(
        '<input type="text" class="service_dt" data-role="datebox" data-options="'{'mode'":"'datebox'","'overrideDateFormat'":"'%d/%m/%Y'","'useNewStyle'":"'true'"}'" placeholder="Date of Service">'
    ).enhanceWithin();
 });
```

Comment: Check your opening/closing quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string interpolation is not looking good. Try this instead:

```
$("#add_Details").click(function () {
    var $input = $('<input type="text" class="service_dt" data-role="datebox" placeholder="Date of Service" />');
    var options = "{'mode':'datebox','overrideDateFormat':'%d/%m/%Y','useNewStyle':'true'}";
    $input.attr('data-options', options); 
    $("#child_service_details").append(
        $input
    ).enhanceWithin();
});
```

Creates this:

```
<input type="text" class="service_dt" data-role="datebox" placeholder="Date of Service" data-options="{'mode':'datebox','overrideDateFormat':'%d/%m/%Y','useNewStyle':'true'}">
```

Comment: i want to append multiple input, can is use this procedure?       can u send me your hangout id please?